# Listar dados somente de um determinado ID

Tags: php, mysql

Fiz um pequeno sistema onde o administrador "envia" documentos para um determinado usuário, onde envia as info para um BD e gera uma pasta com o ID do usuário. Na imagem abaixo está o BD responsável por gravar as informações dos arquivos enviados, como: URL, Nome do Arquivo, Descrição e o ID do usuário para o qual o arquivo foi enviado, que está na tabela Identificação.

[image: Imagem do Banco de Dados onde fica gravado os dados dos arquivos enviados.]

Quando o cliente acessa sua parte administrativa, eu quero listar os documentos que estão com a mesma ID dele, no caso comparar a ID da SESSION e Listar os documentos que estão com a mesma ID.

Abaixo a página onde lista os documentos, mas não da forma que quero, pois não consigo pôr o link para download e nem descrição.

```
require_once 'conexao.php';
include("includes/header.php");  
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '$_SESSION[usuario]' AND senha = '$_SESSION[senha]'") or die(mysql_error());
$cliente = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

$query = mysql_query("SELECT nome,url FROM arquivos") or die(mysql_error());
$arquivos = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
$urlbd = $arquivos['url'];
$id = $cliente['id'];
$nome = $arquivos['nome'];
$dir = "../../restrito/adm/uploads/$id";
$url = "../../restrito/adm/uploads/$id/$nome";
$pasta = opendir($dir);
/* Loop para ler os arquivos do diretorio */
while ($arquivo = readdir($pasta)){
    /* Verificacao para exibir apenas os arquivos e nao os caminhos para diretorios superiores */
    if ($arquivo != '.' && $arquivo != '..'){
        /* Escreve o nome do arquivo na tela */
        echo "<a href='$urlbd' target='_blank'>$arquivo</a><br>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenta isso:

```
require_once 'conexao.php';
include("includes/header.php");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT nome, url FROM arquivos WHERE identificacao = {$_SESSION['usuario']}") or die(mysql_error());
while ($arquivos = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $urlCompleta = "../../restrito/adm/{$arquivo['url']}"; 
    echo "<a href='$urlCompleta' target='_blank'>{$arquivo['nome']}</a><br>";
}
```

Isso deve exibir o nome de cada arquivo que está no banco e foi enviado para o usuário da sessão. Estou assumindo que o índice 'usuario' da sessão  contém o id do usuário.

Uma dica: não use funções `mysql_*`. Use PDO ou algum framework de abstração do banco de dados, como o Doctrine.

E quando você precisa imprimir o valor de um elemento de uma array em uma string, você precisa colocar a variável entre chaves.